# Can we write a docker file without base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

In the below docker file its started with "FROM" keyword but there is no base image mentioned after "FROM" keyword. Can someone clear my doubt why no base image is mentioned after "FROM" keyword.

```
FROM
LABEL name="emp-etl" \
io.openshift.s2i.scripts-url="image:///usr/local/s2i" \
summary="emp-etl" \
description="emp-etl" \
io.k8s.display-name="emp-etl" \
io.k8s.description="emp-etl" \
parent.image="java-open-jdk:1.8.0_331" \
parent.image.1="emp-etl-src:1.28.1" \
image.tag="1.28.1" \
io.openshift.build.source-location=""\
ENV TARGET_DIR="/deployments"
COPY /deployments/= /deployments/
COPY /usr/local/s2i/= /usr/local/s2i
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/s2i/run
```

Comment: Where did this file come from? Did you try building this yourself?

Comment: This file i received from my organisation github repo. I did not try building myself yet. I was just trying to understand this docker file why no source operating system image is included

Comment: `why no base image is mentioned after "FROM" keyword.` ask the author, not us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we write a docker file without base image

No. The base-iest base image is `scratch`.